# How can I SQL update a meta_value to remove the dollar signs that were entered with the value? (so just the value remains)

Tags: mysql

For all the "price" custom fields of a site, the dollar sign was entered *with* the value. I need to remove the dollar sign and leave the *just the values*.

I know very little about SQL queries. The values are all different, so I was hoping I could use UPDATE and the wildcard to effectively delete the dollar sign, but alas, I can't make it happen.

This is what I'm trying to achieve

UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = replace(meta_value, '$%', '%') WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'price'.

Comment: I do not know that from the top of my head, but I'm sure you can look that up in the MySQL manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/

Comment: Are you trying to update all instances of the meta_value for all posts? Or is this something that happens within a theme/plugin?

Comment: Additional note: If you're adding in the currency you'd be better off using another custom field for it, just in case you wanted extra currencies some day.

Answer (score 5):

Why doesn't this work?

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value = REPLACE( meta_value, '$', '' ) 
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'price';
```

Comment: Maybe it will work goldenapples. So that will simply stip the dollar sign and leave the rest of the value?

Comment: Yeah, it should. No reason to leave a wildcard in there (and I don't think you *can* use a wildcard in the replace field)